# "Always on top" window in Kivy

Tags: python, window, kivy, always-on-top

Is there some possible way of setting `kivy.Window` to be always on the top of other windows. I mean something similar to `tkinter.Tk().attributes('-topmost', True)`. I have tried to set `Window.on_hide = Window.raise_window` but with no success.

I need to do this really badly so please write any even complicated solution Any help will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am on Windows 10, python 3.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the win32 python modules (win32api, win32gui, winxpgui…) to get a window handle (e.g: `win32gui.FindWindow(None, NAME)`) then set its properties to stick it on top, using win32gui.SetWindowPos should do the trick, here is the relevant documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yea, thats what I have figured out since yesterday, but thanks :)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the upvote then, i was surprised that you could validate so quickly it was the good answer!

Comment: I am working on the app right now, so you know.. And I love your Kivy framework :)

Answer (score 2):

This question had already answered years ago, but I want to recommend you to use just Python library.

And I strongly recommends you [KivyOnTop](https://pypi.org/project/KivyOnTop/). This is very simple and works well.

You can active AlwaysOnTop mode with `register_topmost(Window, TITLE)`.

Comment: Yeah. I made that library in the end. :D

Comment: Oh, you made this library? It’s really cool!

Answer (score 1):

Kivy doesn't have an API for this. It looks like SDL2, Kivy's main windowing backend, supports it [only on X11](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowFlags), so if that's your platform you could add the functionality. There might be way to do it using a platform-specific method outside of Kivy itself, but I don't know about that.

Comment: I thought it could be done like if the window is hidden, lift it again.